# HTTP 1.1 Persistent connection: Android GET/POST: [FIN/ACK] coming

Tags: java, android, http, android-studio, tcp

I am consuming HTTP GET/POST request in an Android Applicaton, Its doing well(Request And response) however when i refer to wireshark LOG there is [FIN, ACK] is coming, is it means my connection is closing or what? 
My requirement is to make the connection persistent. So my question is why FIN/ACK is coming and if it is closing the connection then where i am leaving?

WireShark LOG and Request/Response content are below:

For GET/POST:

Request:

```
GET /api/application/addparam HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: okhttp/2.5.0
Authorization: Basic QURJOg==
Host: 10.92.33.190:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 558
Date: Fri, 18 May 2018 13:11:46 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
//JSON Here
}
```

WireShark LOG:

```
692 28.537182   10.92.33.134    10.92.33.190    HTTP    329 POST /api/application/AddParam HTTP/1.1  (application/json)
693 28.541340   10.92.33.190    10.92.33.134    HTTP    345 HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/json)
704 29.194478   10.92.33.190    10.92.33.134    TCP 66  8080 → 47074 [FIN, ACK] Seq=289 Ack=334 Win=66048 Len=0 TSval=285850628 TSecr=19045098
709 29.393729   10.92.33.134    10.92.33.190    TCP 66  47074 → 8080 [ACK] Seq=334 Ack=290 Win=88832 Len=0 TSval=19045619 TSecr=285850628   
852 33.544459   10.92.33.190    10.92.33.134    TCP 66  8080 → 45502 [FIN, ACK] Seq=280 Ack=264 Win=66304 Len=0 TSval=285854978 TSecr=19045534

855 33.583848   10.92.33.134    10.92.33.190    TCP 66  45502 → 8080 [ACK] Seq=264 Ack=281 Win=88832 Len=0 TSval=19046038 TSecr=285854978
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the packet capture the connection close is initiated by the server shortly after the response was sent. If and how long the server is keeping the connection open for the next HTTP request within the same TCP connection **solely depends on the server side** and there is no way for the client to tune this. All the client can do is to nicely ask the server to keep the connection open for  another request, which you do by using HTTP/1.1 and also by sending (a redundant) `Connection: keep-alive`. There is **no way for the client to enforce persistent connection or to enforce a minimum time** how long the server should wait for the next request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Steffen. Some times Client is also sending [FIN/ACK] after Server's [FIN/ACK]..if required i can attach other wireshark log aswell: 409 16.644007 10.92.33.134 10.92.33.190 TCP 66 58340 → 8080 [FIN, ACK] Seq=483 Ack=299 Win=88832 Len=0 TSval=19044343 TSecr=285833018

Comment: @SRam: what you describe is the normal flow of closing a TCP connection: one side starts with FIN to signal that it will no longer send data and once the other side sends a FIN too then the connection is considered closed (i.e. nobody will send anything anymore). The relevant part in your problem is which side is sending the first FIN and in your case it is the server.

Comment: By Saying "The relevant part is which side is sending the first FIN and in your case it is the server" i am totally agree. however a liitlle thing in my mind is that HTTP1.1 support persistent connection by default so is there any need to send "Connection: keep-alive" parameter from client because if i don't add keep-alive, HTTP1.1 request add it automatically. so is there any way to prevent the server to send [FIN/ACK] after a short while of 3-5 seconds.or can we increase time duration of sending FIN from server?

Comment: @SRam: to cite myself: *"There is no way for the client to enforce persistent connection or to enforce a minimum time how long the server should wait for the next request."*. In other words, you cannot change the servers behavior from the client side but you would need to have access to the server to do this.

Comment: can you please guide me what is this "Continuation" in request?

Comment: @SRam: I have no idea what you are trying to do know but I think that your original question got fully answered.  If you have more questions please don't ask these inside a comment but ask a new question instead which includes all necessary information.